# Interpolating points to get trajectory

Tags: math, graph, polynomials

Three points

```
A0 [0,0]; A1 [1,2]; A3 [3,3]
```

are interpolated by algebraic polynom and result equation is:

```
p2 = A0*X^2 + A1*X + A0;
```

Is there a way how to calculate [X,Y] of point in interval from <0, 1>?

I'm simply trying to reconstruct object trajectory based on leading points (A0, A1, A2.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not simply want

```
p2[0] = A0[0]*X^2 + A1[0]*X + A2[0]
p2[1] = A0[1]*X^2 + A1[1]*X + A2[1]
```

Comment: I think not. The <0,1> is beginning and end of the trajectory, so if you want move object along the trajectory for ex. into half you just set input parameter to 0.5